# Using Darboux Sums to Prove Upper and Lower Integrals

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Define $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{equation}
f (x) \equiv \left\{\begin{array}{l l} 
x & \text{if } x\in [0, 1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\\
0& \text{if }x\in [0, 1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Prove that the lower Darboux integral of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is $0$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1}, x_i]}f(x)\ \Big|\  x_0=0, x_n=1, x_i\in(0, 1), n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}=0
\end{equation} and that the upper Darboux integral of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is greater than or equal to 0.5, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1}, x_i]}f(x)\ \Big|\  x_0=0, x_n=1, x_i\in(0, 1), n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\geq\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

I think the first part is easy. Let $P=(0, x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, 1)$ be a partition of $[0, 1]$. Then, by the density of the irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists an irrational $x\neq0$ in every subinterval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and $f(x)=0$. Consequently,
\begin{equation}
m_i\equiv \inf_{x\in[x_{i-1}, x_i]}f(x)=0\quad\forall \ i=1, \dots, n.
\end{equation} This is true for any partition whence it follows that the lower Darboux sum is zero.

However, I don't really know what to do for the second part. My teacher hinted that we know 
\begin{equation}
x_i \geq \frac{x_i + x_{i-1}}{2}\quad\forall\ i=1, \dots, n,
\end{equation} but I don't see how this is supposed to help...

(Also, sorry about my inability to format this correctly... Anyone have a link to some beginner instructions on how to format mathematical functions so beautifully? I tried looking stuff up but felt like I only got more and more confused.)

Comment: Hey Bryyo, looks like you are trying to get an introduction to LaTeX! You can look here: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/ . Try jumping straight to the section "Producing Mathematical Formulae using LaTeX".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a series of hints as to how to attack this problem. Start with an arbitrary upper Darboux sum given by some partition $\mathcal{P}$. Each piece of the partition is an interval $[x_{i},x_{i+1}]$. What is the supremum of our function on this interval? We would like to say that it is $x_{i+1}$, since that is when the function $g(x) = x$ is biggest on the interval. Our only concern is that maybe $x_{i+1}$ is irrational, and our function is zero there. However, we know that we can find rationals in our interval arbitrarily close to $x_{i+1}$, so you should be able to prove that $x_{i+1}$ is still the supremum of $f$ on our interval, even if it is not the maximum.

Observe that, by the argument of the prior paragraph, every upper Darboux sum for $f$ is actually an upper Darboux sum for the function $g(x) = x$. What can you then say about the relationship between the upper Darboux integrals of $f$ and $g$? What do you know about the upper Darboux integral of $g$ (which is a function whose integral you can explicitly compute!)?

Comment: Wait, so if you argue that the supremum of f(x) and g(x) are the same, are you saying you're allowed to say that their upper integrals will be equal? And therefore you know it's less than 0.5 because you can calculate the integral directly?

Also, any idea where the x_i > (x_i + x_(i-1))/2 comes in?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The $x_i > (x_i + x_{i-1})/2$ is basically to help you integrate $g(x) = x$ if you didn't know how to do it symbolically.

Comment: Oh, okay. Another thing my professor mentioned is that the tricky part of this part is the fact that it's easy to show for any _regular_ partition, but the statement doesn't specify that we use _regular_ partitions. Any idea what he means by regular partitions? Are there different types of partitions? And where does this come into play?

Comment: I think regular partitions is where each subinterval has the same length. I don't think we made any such assumption here.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. 

Lastly, would you be able to explain the difference between the upper integral and a simple upper sum? The only difference I see is that the upper integral is the infimum of the upper sum. But what does this mean...? The way I want to read it (though I know it's wrong) is that you do all upper sums and the upper integral would be the smallest upper sum...

Comment: You're almost correct, but you need to replace "smallest" with "infimum". That is, you compute all the upper sums and the upper integral is the smallest value these sums tend to (if the minimum doesn't exist, say).

Comment: What do you mean by "tends to"? 

What I'm imagining is that you have f(x) = x, P = {0, .25, .5, .75, 1}. So U(f,P) = 0.25 + 0.125 + 0.1875 + 0.25 = 0.8125, but the upper integral is 0.125 because that is the smallest value within the upper sums...

Comment: The upper integral is not the infimum of the components in a particular sum. It's the infimum of the sum over all partitions $\mathcal{P}$. I think you need to do more reading to get a better understanding of Darboux sums.

Answer (score 0):

When you consider a subinterval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$, by the fact that the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $\sup f([x_{i-1}, x_i]) = x_i$. It may help to visualize a graph of $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$ and the upper sum of any partition (consider the portion of the upper sum below the graph; it's always strictly less than the upper sum itself).